# Android studio: Out of memory on a 176947212-byte allocation

Tags: java, android

In my android studio project I found this problem: 
    "E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 176947212-byte allocation."
    I used "ImageSwitcher" after i put the photos in "Drawable",so the images 
    changes one by one, and when it's in the eighth picture, than the app
    blocked and i noted that is the problem of memory..
    So, i don't know i'll do with that.

This is part of my code:

```
public class Fruits extends AppCompatActivity {

private String answers[] = {"orange" , "apple" , "banana" , "grape" , "ananas" , "cheries" , "kiwi" , "pear" ,
        "strawberry" , "watermelon", "apricot" , "clementine" , "guava" , "nectarine" , "fig"};
private int[] im = {R.drawable.orange,R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.banana,R.drawable.grape,
        R.drawable.ananas,R.drawable.cherries,R.drawable.kiwi,R.drawable.pears,R.drawable.strawberry,R.drawable.watermelon,
        R.drawable.apricot,R.drawable.clementine,R.drawable.guava,R.drawable.nectarine,R.drawable.fig};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruits);
    start();
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

    scores = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_num);
    mimage = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.image);

    mimage.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView imagev = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imagev.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            return imagev;
        }
    });
    mimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
    start();

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edit.getText().toString().equals(answers[k]))
            {
                k++;
                Toast.makeText(Fruits.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sc = sc + 10;
                update_score(sc);
                mimage.setImageResource(im[k]);
                update_edit();
            }
            else
            {
                if(edit.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(Fruits.this,"put a name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                {
                    k++;
                    Toast.makeText(Fruits.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mimage.setImageResource(im[k]);
                    update_edit();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

public void start()
{
    time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    time.setText("00:00");
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(90 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("done");
            Intent i = new Intent(Fruits.this,End.class);
            i.putExtra("score", sc);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
}

public void update_score(int i) { scores.setText("" + i); }
public void update_edit(){ edit.setText(""); }

}
```

Finally, this is the part of memory of my virtual device:
[image]

Comment: That is a lot of bytes, like around 176MB. Why are you surprised? Are you sure you need an image that big?

Comment: Compress the image. Use an online tool, use Picasso(library) and make it smaller in dimensions(why have 1024x1024 when you can have 256x256)

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know the instruction that i use !!

Comment: that 's a pretty big image...

Answer (score 0):

> after i put the photos in "Drawable"

Do not put them in `res/drawable/`. That is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and it will cause Android to resample those images on higher-density screens, contributing to your memory use. Put them in `res/drawable-nodpi/`.

Comment: even then, considering xxxhdpi resampling, the original image is 1440x1920. Still pretty big.

Comment: @njzk2: Agreed. Putting full-size photos as drawable resources is not a good plan in general.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i access to that file(res/drawable-mdpi/), i mean the inctruction?

Comment: @saidbous: All drawable resources are referenced the same way (`R.drawable.whatever` in Java, `@drawable/whatever` in resources and the manifest).